# Using triggerHandler() with the second select element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to automate filling of a form in a page. The form contains multiple select elements (and other elements) but does not have ID or Name for any of the element. Hence I'm getting all the elements using their tag and then modifying the element based on their index. Like this..

```
var $control = $('select');  
$control[index].value = 'Yes';  
$control.triggerHandler('change'); //Triggers the event for first select only  
$control[index].triggerHandler('change'); //Error that the object does not have triggerHandler method
```

The problem I'm facing now is, some of the selects have events attached. These need to be executed immediately after changing the value so that other form fields appear. Using triggerHandler() method is working for the first select element. How do I get it working for the Nth select, if I know the index ? Or, is there any alternative method that will trigger the event associated with a particular select element ?  I'm pretty new to jQuery. Searched previous SO questions but could not find anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to fetch the select element by index

```
$control.eq(index).triggerHandler('change');
```

like

```
var $control = $('select');  
$control.eq(index).val('Yes').triggerHandler('change');
```